# How do I call a full numeric keyboard on Samsung phones via html (input type=number)?

Tags: html, samsung-mobile, numeric-keypad

Currently whenever I have an input type=number field the keyboard that opens on my Samsung S7 is a very simplified numeric input that doesn't allow for negative numbers, ideally how do I let the phone see that I am looking for a fuller keyboard?  I would like this to be possible on all types of phones.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr** - You can't (with any certainty), until the `inputmode` attribute is available, which [isn't going to be any time soon](http://caniuse.com/#search=inputmode).

**Longer version** - `<input type='number'>` is currently interpreted by device/OS manufacturers as they see fit. There is no other standard way AFAIK of hinting to a device what kind of keyboard should show up on focussing that field.

That said, you might be able to have *some* influence on *some* devices by using hacks like that suggested by Chris Coyier, using e.g. `<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*">` which [does apparently work for IOS5](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NmikW6QqaDo). 
Whether or not that works for any other versions of IOS or your Samsung S7 or for each of the other millions of different phones/devices out there is another matter...